# How to put properties with timed events in Mixpanel Android

Tags: android, mixpanel

```
MixpanelAPI mixpanel =
    MixpanelAPI.getInstance(context, MIXPANEL_TOKEN);

// start the timer for the event "Image Upload"
mixpanel.timeEvent("Image Upload");

// stop the timer if the imageUpload() method returns true
if(imageUpload()){`enter code here`
    mixpanel.track("Image Upload");
}
```

Have already tried sending properties with time event , But those are not visible in live view.

Comment: Can you put here your full code?

Comment: MixpanelAPI mixpanel =
    MixpanelAPI.getInstance(context, MIXPANEL_TOKEN);

// start the timer for the event "Image Upload"
mixpanel.timeEvent("Image Upload");

// stop the timer if the imageUpload() method returns true
if(imageUpload()){`enter code here`
JsonObject imageProps= new JsonObject();
imageProps.put("image_urls","http://image_urls");

    mixpanel.track("Image Upload",imageProps);
}

Comment: I have tested it, its working fine, But it display in live if we call it tow time or second time.

Comment: My bad, Yes it is doing. Thanks @DhavalkumarSolanki

Comment: Welcome @Renu Yadav